# Using Multiple Detail View Controller in Split View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am planning to make split view controller by using multiple detail view controller.

I want to change between detail view controllers by pressing cells in the master view controller. My question is: what are the best ways to connect the detail view controllers to the master view controllers by using storyboard? Connecting by using storyboard is preferred because I am going to add more buttons in the new detail view controller.

Your help is greatly appreciated :) please don't be harsh on me because this is my first question

n.b. i cant post image bcs i dont have enough reputation

Comment: Do you mean a completely different detail view controller depending on what button is pressed??

Comment: yup true. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a container view in one of the panes of the split view. I think the ideal way to structure this (though there are many) is to have the "main" side of the split manage what is shown on the detail side. You should use protocols to pass the data is you need to.